# Invalidate all shared ptrs toward a specific managed object

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Is it possible, in C++11, to have an object managed by several `std::shared_ptr`s. I want to delete the object via one `std::shared_ptr` and have the other `shared_ptr`s invalidated (set empty or null), is this possible? If not, what is the best method to inform all other "references" (in a liberal use of the word) that the object is no longer valid?

Comment: Do you always know which one particular `shared_ptr` will do the deletion? Or can it be an arbitrary one?

Comment: Yes, I know which `shared_ptr` will do the deletion.

Comment: Add a level of indirection. Have a wrapper object holding the real object, and have shared pointers to the wrapper. When time comes, instruct the wrapper to drop the real object, at which point it would start reporting some kind of error in its accessors (e.g. return `nullptr` from its `RealObject* getReal()`)

Comment: Why would you want to use that particular smart pointer in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, the other `shared_ptr`s have to be replaced with `weak_ptr`s. The `shared_ptr` that does the deletion is the one actually manages the lifetime of the object in this scenario. It's worthwhile at this point to figure out if you *really* need shared ownership semantics. In general, if you find yourself trying to do something the interface doesn't let you do, that's an indication that you need something with different semantics.

Alternatively, if you really can't manage the object's lifetime from one place, you can use `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<T>>`, but this is more cumbersome (not to mention slower) and is better to avoid. Here you would delete the object by `reset`ting the inner `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) is a good example of `weak_ptr` and to be informed when all other "references" is no longer valid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::weak_ptr<int> gw;

void f()
{
    std::cout << "use_count == " << gw.use_count() << ": ";
    if (auto spt = gw.lock()) 
    { // Has to be copied into a shared_ptr before usage
        std::cout << *spt << "\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "gw is expired\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
        gw = sp;
        f();
    }
    f();
}
```

> Output:
>  use_count == 1: 42
>  use_count == 0: gw is expired